Can I simulate wireless charging on PLECS?
I want to check the voltage fluctuation according to the separation distance of the transmitting/receiving coil on PLECS.
So I used the following block.

I made it through this block as follows.

With this block, can we simulate voltage fluctuations according to the separation distance of the transmission/reception pad?

The images does not appear.
